# How to configure KEDA to create container on basis of metadata in Azure Service Bus Trigger

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, keda

So, I have a Service Bus Queue which is handling two types of messages, for one type of message I want to trigger KEDA however want to restrict KEDA to not instantiate container for other type of message. I can attach properties to the service bus message if that's anyhow it is possible.

I referred https://keda.sh/docs/2.5/scalers/azure-service-bus/ but couldn't find something that's helpful.

Please help if there's a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KEDA Azure Service Bus provides scaling based upon the number of the messages in the queue and not on the message data. You might want to consider creating separate queues based on the message type for your application

Answer (score 0):

KEDA is a scaler, not a resource provisioner. KEDA allows scaling based on the metrics provided by the already provisioned resources.